# Htaccess regex: exclude REQUEST_URI

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I really tried everything, the tool [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) says that it's ok, but it's not really working.

I want to redirect a subdomain to the main domain only if the REQUEST_URI doesn't start with 3 specific strings.

I tried without success with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(aaa|bbb|ccc)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

I want that:

- `http://sub.example.com` (shouldn't redirect) -> `http://sub.example.com` | OK
- `http://sub.example.com/aaa/sss` (shouldn't redirect) -> `http://sub.example.com/aaa/sss` | KO (redirect to http://www...)
- `http://sub.example.com/zzz/xxx` (should redirect) -> `http://www.example.com/zzz/xxx` | OK

Thanks

Comment: What's happening that you don't want?

Comment: it redirects the second to `http://www.example.com/aaa/sss`

Comment: You may want to add that to your question, and the specific strings are all letters or do they include symbols?

Comment: added, thanks.. only letters

Comment: Is this your full .htaccess code because nothing is wrong here? Make sure you copied everything correctly.

Comment: I removed everything else in the htaccess

Comment: Then can you show the actual line you use instead of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(aaa|bbb|ccc)` since that line is likely the problem?

Comment: OH! there was this 3 lines below that was causing problems.. https://gist.github.com/pensiero/ffbc62aa222e9f76f203
How can i do without removing them?

Comment: Oh, well, that complicates things. What is that supposed to do exactly?

Comment: it's something of ZF2, however, i resolved with the code posted by @anubhava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(aaa|bbb|ccc)/ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache.

Using `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` to make sure we use unchanged URI values as received by Apache.